# VT enabled processor in my Dell Inspiron 530

Tags: bios, vt-x

I have an Inspiron 530 with a Q8200 processor.  The problem is that I want to run Windows Server 2008 R2 inside VMWare but that is only 64-bit.  To run a 64-bit guest you need to have Intel VT support.  My processor [does not support it](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=36547).  If I were to get a new processor, would I then be able to enable VT in the bios? Currently there is no option to do so (Not greyed out or anything like that, just isn't there).

Comment: If there's no option there, it may be because the BIOS doesn't support it either.

Answer (score 1):

1. Windows Server 2008 is available in 32-bit and 64-bit flavors. (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2008)
2. I know of a BIOS mentioned in some other webpage that enables VT extension in Inspiron 530 BIOS. You may download it here: http://thelostbrain.com/file.axd?file=AllRaid-Inspiron-530%2b530s-1016.zip (Source: http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/desktop/f/3514/t/19270710.aspx?PageIndex=2)
3. If you are going to pay the price and run Windows Server 2008, I think you may as well buy a new computer which cost perhaps one fifth of the cost of windows server 2008 - running windows server 2008 virtualised do not seem a very good idea to me.

Comment: Thanks for number 2.  But with number 1 I am pretty sure R2 is 64 bit only (unlike plain 2008). With number 3, this is for development purposes, not production.

Comment: Sorry I overlooked the R2. You are correct that R2 is 64bit only.